# jq query json key based on key value filter

Tags: python, json, jq

I have a json file with key and the value is a json with key value pair. I would like to filter and extract the key based on the inner key value pair. Any help is greatly appreciated

Example json data:

```
{
    "key1": {
      "filterkey": "filtervalue",
      "key1": "value1"
    },
    "key2": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

- Filter: "filterkey": "filtervalue"
- expected output: "key1"

Comment: do you need this to work at any arbitrary depth of the json or just at the top level? Do you really expect `"key1"` or rather `["key1"]` as there might be more than one keys present?

Comment: @M.Rau the json depth is going to be the same always.. just that there will be more keys

Comment: Please enhance the example by avoiding the repetition of "key1".

Answer (score 0):

if your input json is stable and you do not need to control any edge cases (arbitrary depth, a top-level type mismatch, e.g. `"key1": "not a dict"`) then this solves your problem:

```
ret = []
for k, v in js.items():
    if v.get("filterkey") == "filtervalue":
        ret.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run snippet to see output:

```js
    var jsonObject = {
                        "key1": {
                            "filterkey": "filtervalue",
                            "key1": "value1"
                        },
                        "key2": {
                            "key1": "value1",
                            "key2": "value2"
                        }
                    };
    function filterKey(jsonObject, keySearch, valueSearch) {
        var result = null;
        for (const key in jsonObject) {
            if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key) && 
                jsonObject[key][keySearch] !== undefined && 
                jsonObject[key][keySearch] === valueSearch) {
                result = key;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    alert(filterKey(jsonObject, 'filterkey', 'filtervalue'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.[] | select( .filterkey == "filtervalue") | to_entries[1]| .key'   sample.json
```

Select by filterkey, turn the objects into key value entires, then take the second entry's key. Output is:

```
"key1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, "key1" appears several times, but it looks like you want the outermost key name.  If that's the case, then using `to_entries` is a good way to go, e.g.:

```
to_entries[]
| if .value.filterkey == "filtervalue" then .key else empty end
```

Or equivalently:

```
to_entries[]
| select(.value.filterkey == "filtervalue" )
| .key
```